# How to get the file name and file size for the attachment of my custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I am making a plugin with a custom post_type called `circular` I use a meta box to upload PDF or image file now I can retrive the url of the file but how can I get the file name and size from my custom post_type meta field .

Here is my Meta Box code

```
function add_custom_meta_boxes() {

    // Define the custom attachment for posts
    add_meta_box(
        'wp_custom_attachment',
        'Custom Attachment',
        'wp_custom_attachment',
        'circular',
        'side'
    );

} // end add_custom_meta_boxes
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_custom_meta_boxes');

function wp_custom_attachment() {

    wp_nonce_field(plugin_basename(__FILE__), 'wp_custom_attachment_nonce');

    $html = '<p class="description">';
        $html .= 'Upload your PDF here.';
    $html .= '</p>';
    $html .= '<input type="file" id="wp_custom_attachment" name="wp_custom_attachment" value="" size="25" />';

    echo $html;

} // end wp_custom_attachment


function save_custom_meta_data($id) {

    /* --- security verification --- */
    if(!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['wp_custom_attachment_nonce'], plugin_basename(__FILE__))) {
      return $id;
    } // end if

    if(defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
      return $id;
    } // end if

    if('circular' == $_POST['post_type']) {
      if(!current_user_can('edit_page', $id)) {
        return $id;
      } // end if
    } else {
        if(!current_user_can('edit_page', $id)) {
            return $id;
        } // end if
    } // end if
    /* - end security verification - */

    // Make sure the file array isn't empty
    if(!empty($_FILES['wp_custom_attachment']['name'])) {

        // Setup the array of supported file types. In this case, it's just PDF.
        $supported_types = array('application/pdf');

        // Get the file type of the upload
        $arr_file_type = wp_check_filetype(basename($_FILES['wp_custom_attachment']['name']));
        $uploaded_type = $arr_file_type['type'];

        // Check if the type is supported. If not, throw an error.
        if(in_array($uploaded_type, $supported_types)) {

            // Use the WordPress API to upload the file
            $upload = wp_upload_bits($_FILES['wp_custom_attachment']['name'], null, file_get_contents($_FILES['wp_custom_attachment']['tmp_name']));

            if(isset($upload['error']) && $upload['error'] != 0) {
                wp_die('There was an error uploading your file. The error is: ' . $upload['error']);
            } else {
                add_post_meta($id, 'wp_custom_attachment', $upload);
                update_post_meta($id, 'wp_custom_attachment', $upload);     
            } // end if/else

        } else {
            wp_die("The file type that you've uploaded is not a PDF.");
        } // end if/else

    } // end if

} // end save_custom_meta_data
add_action('save_post', 'save_custom_meta_data');

function update_edit_form() {
    echo ' enctype="multipart/form-data"';
} // end update_edit_form
add_action('post_edit_form_tag', 'update_edit_form');
```

**do out put the link of that file**

```
<?php $img = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'wp_custom_attachment', true); ?>
<a href="<?php echo $img['url']; ?>"> Download PDF Here</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First need to get the file url the we can get the size and name . here `wp_custom_attachment` is the custom field id.

```
 // retrieve file of the custom field 
 $file = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'wp_custom_attachment', true); 

 //get the url
 $url = $file['url'];

 //Replace url to directory path
  $path = str_replace( site_url('/'), ABSPATH, esc_url( $url) );

  if ( is_file( $path ) ){
    $filesize = size_format( filesize( $path ) );
    $filename = basename($path); 
  }

            echo '<p>Name: ' . $filename . '</p>';
            echo '<p>Size: ' . $filesize . '</p>';
```

Comment: In your `get_post_meta()` you have the `$single` parameter set to true which returns the "[value of meta data field](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/#return)". I think you `$file` variable is the image ID number maybe. Can you try `var_dump($file)` there to see what `get_post_meta()` is returning?

Comment: `size_format` is the function which return the filesize correctly

Comment: did you try the `getSize()` function I mentioned in my previous answer??

Answer (score 1):

If you can get the attachment ID number ($attachment_id below) you should be able to do something like this to get the name/size:

```
$attachment_id = 'YOUR_PDF_ID';
$attahment_file = get_attached_file( $attachment_id );

function getSize($file) {
    $bytes = filesize($file);
    $s = array('b', 'Kb', 'Mb', 'Gb');
    $e = floor(log($bytes)/log(1024));
    return sprintf( '%.2f ' . $s[$e], ( $bytes/pow( 1024, floor($e) ) ) );
}

echo '<p>Name: ' . basename( $attahment_file ) . '</p>';
echo '<p>Size: ' . getSize( $attahment_file ) . '</p>';
```

I found the "getSize" function on another post [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/546). It was more accurate than using the native PHP "filesize" function in terms of matching the size shown in the WP media library meta.

Comment: Which part is not working? I believe I tested the code before posting it, can you give more information so I can help debug?

Comment: I have used your code but its return a null value not sure why maybe its a custom post type? or in your code `$attahment_file` should be an array and `getSize($file)` here the $file has no value I try to modify your code but failed. But bellow answer is working perfect. Thanks for the support man.